# spring-data-rest, common custom method for all repositories

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I try to create a base functionality for all my spring-data-rest repositories, but have an insistent problem.

The version of spring is 4.2.4, i have UserRepository, bound to relative User entity, also a UserController managing multi-repo related logic.

I want to add a custom method `sharedCustomMethod` to all my repos including UserRepository.

I have BaseRepositoryRelated classes and interfaces:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository <T, E extends Serializable> 
extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, E>, BaseRepositoryCustom<T, Serializable> {

    @Override
    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.enabled=1 and e.id=?1")
    T findOne(E primaryKey);

    @Override
    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.enabled=1")
    Iterable<T> findAll(); 

    @Override
    @Query("select count(*) from #{#entityName} e where e.enabled=1")
    long count();

    @Override
    @Query("update #{#entityName} e set e.enabled=0 where e.id=?1")
    @Modifying
    void delete(E primaryKey);
}
```

Custom Interface:

```
package com.eolcum.repository.base;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepositoryCustom <T, E extends Serializable> {

    void sharedCustomMethod(E id);
}
```

Custom Impl:

```
package com.eolcum.repository.base;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> 
    extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, Serializable> 
    implements BaseRepository<T, Serializable> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.entityManager = em;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void sharedCustomMethod(Serializable id) {
        System.out.println("done!");

    }

}
```

BaseRepo Factory Bean:

```
package com.eolcum.repository.base;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryInformation;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class BaseRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T,
        I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {
        return new BaseRepositoryFactory(em);
    }

    private static class BaseRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable>
            extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private final EntityManager em;

        public BaseRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {
            super(em);
            this.em = em;
        }

        @Override
        protected SimpleJpaRepository<T, Serializable> getTargetRepository(RepositoryInformation information,
                EntityManager entityManager) {
            return new BaseRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) information.getDomainType(), em);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return BaseRepositoryImpl.class;
        }
    }
}
```

PersistenceContext:
    package com.eolcum.repository.base;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.eolcum.controller.UserController;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.eolcum.repository.base"}, 
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceContext {

}
```

When I try to run the app with spring-boot i get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eolcum.repository.UserRepository com.eolcum.controller.UserController.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property sharedCustomMethod found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.eolcum.Application.main(Application.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eolcum.repository.UserRepository com.eolcum.controller.UserController.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property sharedCustomMethod found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property sharedCustomMethod found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property sharedCustomMethod found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create base interface with **@NoRepository** annotation like below:

   ```
   @NoRepositoryBean
   public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseModel, ID extends Serializable>
           extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

       T checkAsDeleted(T t);

   }
   ```
2. Create base class and extend your base interface

   ```
   @Transactional(readOnly = false)
   public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T extends BaseModel, ID extends Serializable>
       extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>
       implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

       public BaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
           super(entityInformation, entityManager);
       }

       public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
           super(domainClass, em);
       }

       @Override
       public T checkAsDeleted(T t) {
           t.setIsDeleted(true);
           return this.save(t);
       }

       @Override
       public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
           Date now = new Date();
           if (entity.getId() == null) {
               entity.setCreationDate(now);
           }
           entity.setModifiedDate(now);
           return super.save(entity);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Extend your repository interface with base interface

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface QuestionRepository extends BaseRepository<Question, Long> {

       List<Question> findByisDeleted(boolean isDeleted);

       List<Question> findAll();

   }
   ```
4. Let know this base class to your application

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
   @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
   public class Application {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }
   }
   ```

Now, you have **checkAsDeleted()** method everywhere!

All codes are working in real project